# do we create google oauth app based on application domain to not to register each sub domain as Authorized JavaScript origins and redirect uri?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-api, google-oauth

Currently i am working on a multitenant app. when a company get registered it has its own url actually we have one subdomain for each company.
 we have a attchments component in our application with which a user can access its google drive account and can download the attachments. in the oauth app do we have to register each sub domain for every company as an redirect uri. is there a way we can create oauth app based on domain level so that we don't have have to register each subdomain.
 Thanks in advance

Comment: The redirect_uri is used to exchange the OAuth tokens. Unless you have one service (URL) handling all authorization (OAuth Flows), you will need to create separate accounts (Client ID / Client Secret) for each subdomain.

Comment: @JohnHanley i have done the same. give one configuration tab in which company will add client id and secret after creating its own oauth app  registering its company url following the given instructions. but clients need we have to create one app for domain level. i have also check the flow of Jira of microsoft its an mutitenant app also have same attachment component but how they manage the things to work. as they don't require such configuration it means they handle maybe at domain level